# bootstrap collapse not working with Angular2 tags

Tags: angular

I am using angular seed advanced and now i want a menu which will be collapsed.

I am using bootstrap. I do not want to use Jquery.

```
  <!-- inject:css -->


  <!-- endinject -->


      <nav _ngcontent-c0="" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="container-fluid">
          <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="navbar-header">
            <button _ngcontent-c0="" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
              <span _ngcontent-c0="" class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span _ngcontent-c0="" class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
              <span _ngcontent-c0="" class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
              <span _ngcontent-c0="" class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a _ngcontent-c0="" class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul _ngcontent-c0="" class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li _ngcontent-c0="" class="active"><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="#">About</a></li>
              <li _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li _ngcontent-c0="" class="dropdown">
                <a _ngcontent-c0="" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button">Dropdown <span _ngcontent-c0="" class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul _ngcontent-c0="" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li _ngcontent-c0="" class="divider"></li>
                  <li _ngcontent-c0="" class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul _ngcontent-c0="" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li _ngcontent-c0="" class="active"><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="./">Default <span _ngcontent-c0="" class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
              <li _ngcontent-c0=""><a _ngcontent-c0="" href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fehr739r/

Kindly help me. It is not working

Answer (score 0):

Because Bootstrap requires jQuery for some components.
You can use [bootstrap-without-jquery](https://github.com/tagawa/bootstrap-without-jquery) or
[Native Angular widgets for Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/)